# Haskell Lazy Evaluation and Reuse

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, lazy-evaluation

I know that if I were to compute a list of squares in Haskell, I could do this:

```
squares = [ x ** 2 | x <- [1 ..] ]
```

Then when I call squares like this:

```
print $ take 4 squares
```

And it would print out [1.0, 4.0, 9.0, 16.0]. This gets evaluated as [ 1 ** 2, 2 ** 2, 3 ** 2, 4 ** 2 ]. Now since Haskell is functional and the result would be the same each time, if I were to call squares again somewhere else, would it re-evaluate the answers it's already computed? If I were to re-use squares after I had already called the previous line, would it re-calculate the first 4 values?

```
print $ take 5 squares
```

Would it evaluate [1.0, 4.0, 9.0, 16.0, 5 ** 2]?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In this case, it won't be recalculated because the list actually gets built, and the squares list continues to exist after the call. However, Haskell functions in general are not memoized. This only works for a case like this where you're not explicitly calling a function, just exploring an (in)finite list.

Comment: Is there any chance you could give me an example of something that would not be memoized? I thought squares was a function that returned an infinite list. Is there anything that I could pass into ghc to see what Haskell is doing under the covers?

Comment: No, squares is *not* a function; it's a list. Data structures are automatically memoized in Haskell, not functions. You can still memoize functions, but you have to do so explicitly. If you're confused about squares not being a function, you might like the blog post [*"Everything is a function" in Haskell?*](http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell/).

Answer (score 13):

This value `squares` is potentially polymorphic:

```
Prelude> :t [ x ** 2 | x <- [1 ..] ]
[ x ** 2 | x <- [1 ..] ] :: (Floating t, Enum t) => [t]
```

AFAIK, whether or not it will be recalculated (in GHC) depends on whether the top-level value `squares` is given a polymorphic type.  I believe that GHC does not do any memoization of polymorphic values involving type classes (functions from types to values), just as it does not do any memoization of ordinary functions (functions from values to values).

That means if you define `squares` by

```
squares :: [Double]
squares = [ x ** 2 | x <- [1 ..] ]
```

then `squares` will only be computed once, while if you define it by

```
squares :: (Floating t, Enum t) => [t]
squares = [ x ** 2 | x <- [1 ..] ]
```

then it will likely be computed each time it is used, even if it's used repeatedly at the same type.  (I haven't tested this, though, and it's possible that GHC, if it sees several uses of `squares :: [Double]`, could specialize the `squares` value to that type and share the resulting value.)  Certainly if `squares` is used at several different types, like `squares :: [Double]` and `squares :: [Float]`, it will be recalculated.

If you don't give any type signature for `squares`, then the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-930004.5.5) will apply to it, unless you have it disabled.  The result will be that `squares` is assigned a monomorphic type, inferred from the rest of your program (or according to the defaulting rules).  The purpose of the monomorphism restriction is exactly to ensure that values that look like they will only be evaluated once, such as your `squares`, really will only be evaluated once.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify an answer already given, this is a Haskell function:

```
thisManySquares n = map (^2) [1..n]
```

So, if you substituted calls of "`thisManySquares 4`" for your `take 4 squares`, then yes, it would call the function repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use ghci to test (if ghc is your compiler):

```
Prelude> let squares = [ x ** 2 | x <- [1 ..] ] :: [Float]
Prelude> :print squares
squares = (_t6::[Float])
```

So all ghci knows right now it that you have a list.

```
Prelude> print $ take 4 squares
[1.0,4.0,9.0,16.0]
Prelude> :print squares
squares = 1.0 : 4.0 : 9.0 : 16.0 : (_t7::[Float])
```

Know it knows that your list begins with stuff, because to it had to evaluate to print it.

```
Prelude> let z = take 5 squares
Prelude> :print z
z = (_t8::[Float])
```

take 5 by itself doesn't evaluate anything

```
Prelude> length z --Evaluate the skeleton
5
Prelude> :print z
z = [1.0,4.0,9.0,16.0,(_t9::Float)]
```

Taking the length causes `take` to run its course, and we see that you were right. You can test what's happening when its polymorphic as well, by just omitting the type definition on squares. Another good trick if you don't want to use ghci is to use `undefined` in your code (your program crashes exactly when it attempts to evaluate a `_|_`, which `undefined` is a type of.)