# Evaluation of list-comprehensions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I am wondering exactly how list-comprehensions are evaluated in Haskell. After reading this [Removing syntactic sugar: List comprehension in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029046/removing-syntactic-sugar-list-comprehension-in-haskell) and this: [Haskell Lazy Evaluation and Reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532443/haskell-lazy-evaluation-and-reuse) I still don't really understand if

```
[<function> x|x <- <someList>, <somePredicate>]
```

is actually exactly equivalent (not just in outcome but in evaluation) to

```
filter (<somePredicate>) . map (<function>) $ <someList>
```

and if so, does this mean it can potentially reduce time complexity drastically to build up the desired list with only desired elements? 
Also, how does this work in terms of infinite lists? To be specific: I assume something like:

```
[x|x <- [1..], x < 20]
```

will be evaluated in finite time, but how "obvious" does the fact that there are no more elements above some value which satisfy the predicate need to be, for the compiler to consider it? Would

```
[x|x <- [1..], (sum.map factorial $ digits x) == x]
```

work (see project Euler problem 34 https://projecteuler.net/problem=34). There is obviously an upper bound because from some x on x*9! < 10^n -1 always holds, but do I need to supply that bound or will the compiler find it?

Comment: evaluation of `[x|x <- [1..], x < 20]` would not terminate so I don't know what you mean by how it 'will be just fine'. No attempt to reason about the predicate is done at all.

Comment: @Lee: I suppose you can take up to 19 elements from `[x | x <- [1..], x < 20]` safely, and _after that_ an attempt to find another element matching the predicate never terminates.

Comment: I mean are the filter (p) . map (f) $ list and [f x|x <- list, p] evaluated the same way or is it possible for the compiler to do optimizations better in one than the other?

Comment: A list comprehension desugars to monadic code (using the `guard` function), not a composition of `filter` and `map`.

Comment: What do you think should `filter (<20) ([1..]++[1])` yield, it is not too much different from your original example

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: I think `filter (< finiteNumber) ([1..] ++ [1])` _should_ give a list of length finiteNumber, however I understand now that it will not. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing obvious about the fact that a particular infinite sequence has no more elements matching a predicate. When you pass a list to `filter`, it has no way of knowing any other properties of the elements than that an element can be passed to the predicate.

You can write your own version of `Ord a => List a` which can describe a sequence as ascending or not, and a version of `filter` that can use this information to stop looking at elements past a particular threshold. Unfortunately, list comprehensions won't use either of them.

Instead, I'd use a combination of `takeWhile` and a comprehension without a predicate / a plain `map`. Somewhere in the `takeWhile` arguments, you will supply the compiler the information about the expected upper bound; for a number of *n* decimal digits, it would be 10^*n*.

Comment: so this basically means list-comprehensions can really screw you over... thanks a lot for the quick answer. I don't have a specific problem I am trying to optimize but as I am new to Haskell I try to get a better understanding of what the compiler will do for you and what not.

Comment: @Chris: it's not comprehensions, it's infinite sequences that need handling with care; infinite loops in any other language need an extra bit of attention, too.

Answer (score 3):

```
[<function> x|x <- <someList>, <somePredicate>]
```

should always *evaluate* to the same result as

```
filter (<somePredicate>) . map (<function>) $ <someList>
```

However, there is *no guarantee* that this is how the compiler will actually do it. [The section on list comprehensions in the Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.11) only mentions *what* list comprehensions should do, not *how* they should work. So each compiler is free to do as its developers find best. Therefore, you should not assume anything about the performance of list comprehensions or that the compiler will do any optimizations.